# How do I convert from a DataBase to Serialization with Lists

Tags: java, serialization, jtable, linked-list

I have this applications where I've used a `MySQL` server to store and use 5 tables of information. Whenever I had to represent the information - I would use a jTable like this:

```
# ID Name Info1 Info2 ...
=========================================
1 231 foo bar troll
2 244 .. .. .. 
3 246 .. .. ..
..
.
```

The ID here is the same primary ID that is stored in the tables. When i wanted the user to select / edit one of these records - I would apply a `SelectionListener` on the `jtable`, read the ID on the selected row, and apply the changes to that object in the Database (using the ID I read)

Now, I'm trying to convert my application for use with serialized objects and will be storing the state in files. Data will be stored using `LinkedList` and I will be serializing the lists themselves into files (not individual data entries).

My question is - How do I use `LinkedList` with `jTable` such that the user is still able to select / make changes / sort through the `jTable`.

To be more specific

1. How do I know which item the user has selected in the `jTable` - should I use index matching? Or should I insert an ID attribute into the base objects?
2. How do I perform sorting in the `LinkedList` on the basis of object attributes (like sort by name, info1, etc.)

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom table model.  Extend DefaultTableModel and return the data from your LinkedList in your model.  You can also implement the setValueAt method to have JTable changes update the LinkedList.